# Highlight charts Automatic zooming problem

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

Currently, bootstrapping is used to
We are building the site.

I have the chart period to show 100 days,
It is in col-8 and when I make it narrower, it auto-zooms,
The chart is not displayed for 100 days.

When I display it at full width, it is displayed without any problem.
I would like to know the cause and solution.

[Full width correctly shows 100 days.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d5JG.png)

[If you put it in col-8, it will not be displayed for 100 days and will be auto-zoomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpF4o.png)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row g-5">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="charts">
                <div class="" id="container" style="height: 700px; min-width: 310px"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

```
<script> (async() => {
    const data = await fetch("/crypto_price/{{ crypto.id }}?days_range=100").then(response => response.json());
    // split the data set into ohlc and volume
    const ohlc = [],
    volume = [],
    dataLength = data.length,
    // set the allowed units for data grouping
    groupingUnits = [
        ['day', // unit name
            [1] // allowed multiples
        ]
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
        ohlc.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][1], // open
            data[i][2], // high
            data[i][3], // low
            data[i][4] // close
        ]);
        volume.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][5] // the volume
        ]);
    }
    // create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },
        title: {
            text: "{{ crypto.coin_name }} Chart"
        },
        yAxis: [
            {
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'OHLC'
                },
                height: '60%',
                lineWidth: 2,
                resize: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }, 
            {
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume'
                },
                top: '65%',
                height: '35%',
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2
            }
        ],
        tooltip: {
            split: true
        },
        series: [
            {
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: "{{ crypto.coin_name }}",
                data: ohlc,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, 
            {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: volume,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }
        ]
    });
})(); 
</script>
```

I tried disabling rangeSelector, and responsive settings, but the chart remained zoomed